# MYSQL PHP API - Displaying & Fetching multiple rows within rows from another table

Tags: php, mysql, api

I'm creating an API for my mobile application. I'm developing this with PHP MYSQL and the Slim framework (which is largely irrelevant for this problem).

I'm trying to pull multiple "venues" from my mysql database, and retrieve multiple "venue_images" for each "venue". The database:

```
venues        venue_images
------        ------------
id PK         image_venue_id FK (to venues)
venue_name    image_path
active
```

**I then need to output the data in this format:**

```
{
  "completed_in":0.01068,
  "returned":10,
  "results":[
    {
      "venue_id":"1",
      "venue_name":"NameHere",
      "images": [
         {
           "image_path":"http://www.pathhere.com"
         },
         {
           "image_path":"http://www.pathhere2.com"
         }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So basically, the images are iterated multiple times for each venue.

**My current code is:**

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
         venues.id, venues.venue_name, venues.active,
         venue_images.image_venue_id, venue_images.image_path
    FROM
         venues
    LEFT JOIN 
         venue_images ON venue_images.image_venue_id = venues.id
    WHERE
         venues.active = 1
    LIMIT 0, 10
    ";

    $data = ORM::for_table('venues')->raw_query($sql, array())->find_many();
         if($data) {
        foreach ($data as $post) {
            $results[] = array (
                 'venue_id' => $post->id,
                 'venue_name' => $post->venue_name,
                 'images' => $post->image_path
            );
        }

        //Build full json
        $time = round((microTimer() - START_TIME), 5);
        $result = array(
             'completed_in' => $time,
             'returned' => count($results),
             'results' => $results
        );
        //Print JSON
        echo indent(stripslashes(json_encode($result)));
    } else {
         echo "Nothing found";
    }
```

**My current code works, however it produces this:**

```
{
  "completed_in":0.01068,
  "returned":10,
  "results":[
    {
      "venue_id":"1",
      "venue_name":"The Bunker",
      "images":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/barholla/venues/1352383950-qPXNShGR6ikoafj_n.jpg"
    },
    {
      "venue_id":"1",
      "venue_name":"The Bunker",
      "images":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/barholla/venues/1352384236-RUfkGAWsCfAVdPm_n.jpg"
    }
]
}
```

There's two images for "The Bunker". Instead of storing the images within the venue array, it's creating a duplicate row of "The Bunker", with the second image. Like I said earlier, I need to have multiple images iterating within each venue. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What's the output of the query taken alone? Does it generate all the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use GROUP_CONCAT

Something like this (not 100% accurate probably :) )

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
         v.id, v.venue_name, v.active,
         GROUP_CONCAT(i.image_path) as venue_image_string
    FROM
         venues v
    LEFT JOIN 
         venue_images i ON i.image_venue_id = v.id
    WHERE
         v.active = 1
    GROUP BY i.image_venue_id
    LIMIT 0, 10
";
```

You may have to fiddle a little but should put you on the right track (note: provides venue_image_string as CSV)

Comment: The group concat would (ought to...) put images together, but it won't produce the right format.

Comment: it'll work just fine once he has his distinct items + a csv list of all the images. its just a small matter of exploding out his image column into an array and and dumping that into a sub array of his primary array. The json encode will take care of the rest

Comment: OK, I get it now... And it does simplify parsing. +1.

Comment: Yeah it should be a fairly minor change to his code but produce the output he needs thanks to the wonders of the json_encode() function :)

Comment: Okay, I see what to do. Like you said, I'll need to explode the contents of venue_image_string. Thanks for your help!

Comment: yeah 'images' => explode(",",$post->image_path)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use multiple queries instead of..? Its faster and simple..!

```
$sql = "SELECT venues.id, venues.venue_name, venues.active FROM venues WHERE venues.active = 1 LIMIT 0, 10";

    $data = ORM::for_table('venues')->raw_query($sql, array())->find_many();
         if($data) {
        foreach ($data as $post) {
            $results[] = array ();

$sql = "SELECT image_path FROM venue_images WHERE image_venue_id = $post->id"; 
$images = ORM::for_table('venue_images')->raw_query($sql, array())->find_many();

 $results[] = array (
                 'venue_id' => $post->id,
                 'venue_name' => $post->venue_name, 
                 'images' => $images);
        }

        //Build full json
        $time = round((microTimer() - START_TIME), 5);
        $result = array(
             'completed_in' => $time,
             'returned' => count($results),
             'results' => $results
        );
        //Print JSON
        echo indent(stripslashes(json_encode($result)));
    } else {
         echo "Nothing found";
    }
```

Comment: Is it faster? To execute I mean. My approach was always to avoid multiple queries to the DB where I can.

Comment: slower, extra load on the db server, potentially more connections especially bad on a heavily loaded server. doing everything in a single query is far more efficient if using specific result sets especially if in the future you implement say memcached etc.

Comment: @Dave.. I think its good for small apps and mostly heavy traffic sites/apps use memcache and master-slave dB servers so it won't be problem for them as well i guess!