# Handling One to Many relations when Exporting Data into CSV

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv, yii

i have a database which contains 11 tables 9 of which have a one to many relation with a User Information table.

User Table:

```
ID , Name , Age , phone , . .......
```

on basis of ID the relation is with tables for e.g

```
User_cars
ID,User_ID(fk),Make , Model , .....
```

What i need to be able to do is present this data in DB in a CSV file. Since the There is a one to many relation a simple join doesnt work as rows are duplicated.(Not presentable Format for the client :S)

Im using Yii as web app and need some extension which can present it in some readable way.

or maybe a php script can do the task as well.

Comment: see this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500748/mysql-php-api-displaying-fetching-multiple-rows-within-rows-from-another-tab/14501190#14501190) its a very similar question. You can use joins + group_concat to do it for you.

Comment: So your question is to come up with a readable format of your data?

Comment: yes jack thts my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can handle it in one of two ways:

**1.** Use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/) (as @Dave mentioned in the comment - this is the link: [MYSQL PHP API - Displaying & Fetching multiple rows within rows from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500748/mysql-php-api-displaying-fetching-multiple-rows-within-rows-from-another-tab/14501190#14501190)). 
There is a downside however, GROUP_CONCAT has a limit (by default 1024 characters), which you can change with the server variable `group_concat_max_len`, but you may not have access to do so.

This will look pretty much like this:

```
ID | Name | Car Model           | Year
1    John   BMW, Audi, Renault    1999, 2000, 2003
2    David  Mercedes, Ford        2000, 2005
```

This can get very complicated if there are 30-40 entries per user, and non-readable.

**2.** The second option is to export it in the following format (not hard to do, you just iterate through all the cars a user has, but write the user only in the first iteration).

---

```
ID | Name | Car Model | Year
1    John   BMW         1999
            Audi        2000
            Renault     2003
2    David .....
```

Here's some sample code (I use plenty of made up methods, that have suggestive names).

```
$csvArray = array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $cars = $user->getCars(); //random method name. Grabs an array with the cars this user has :)


    $firstIteration = 1;
    foreach ($cars as $car) {
         if ($firstIteration == 1) { // we only set the CSV row the first time we iterate through cars
             $csvSingle['ID'] = $user->getId(); // more random method names
             $csvSingle['Name'] = $user->getName();
             $firstIteration = 0;
         }
        $csvSingle['car_model'] = $car->getCarModel();
        $csvSingle['car_year'] = $car->getCarYear();

        $csvArray[] = $csvSingle; // now we add the single row to the big CSV array.
    }

}

fputcsv($handle, $csvArray); // $handle is the file you export to
```

Comment: Thanks this pretty much explains the two choices i have. thankyou very much vlad , dave and jack and yessi

Comment: Very good, thanks for the examples. Ill definitely use the second approach though

Comment: @"Vlad Preda" @gakker How we will modify the 2nd option code if we have multiple OneToMany relations? Assume we have bikes linked to users as well.

Answer (score 0):

i like first variant by @"Vlad Preda" and in your controller or component for export you can use something like this:

1. get users with cars (and cars must fill in user model relations)

   $users = User::model()->with('cars')->findAll();
2. and then

   foreach ($users as $user) {

   $csvOneUser = array('id'=>$user->id, "name"=>$user->name);

   if (!$user->cars) {

   ```
   $csvAll[] = $csvOneUser;

   continue;
   ```

   }

   foreach ($user->cars as $car) {

   ```
   $car_attributes = $car->getAttributes();

   foreach ($car_attributes as $k=>$v) {

     $csvOneUser[$k][] = $v;

   }
   ```

   }

   }